# On GCP, using the python pubsub client, how to list only a subset of subscriptions based on a filter

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-python

On the `gcloud` cli, when listing the pubsub subscriptions of a project, it is possible to filter results by [using the `--filter` flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/list). Here is an example:

```
gcloud --project=my-project pubsub subscriptions list --filter=my-filter-string --format='value(name)'
```

I did not manage to find out how to do this with the python library and its [`list_subscription` method](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client#google_cloud_pubsub_v1_subscriber_client_Client_list_subscriptions).

It seems to only basically accept a `project` string and to return all subscriptions in the project. This means I would need to get all the subscriptions in the project and then loop through them to filter them, as follows:

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

subscriber_client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

filter = "my-filter-string"

with subscriber_client:
    page_result = subscriber_client.list_subscriptions(
            project="projects/my-project",
        )
    filtered_subscriptions = [
        subscription.name
        for subscription in page_result
        if filter in subscription.name.split("/")[-1]
    ]
    for subscription_name in filtered_subscriptions:
        print(subscription_name)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do that ?

I have been trying to do this with the `metadata: Sequence[Tuple[str, str]]` argument on the method, but could not find examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the [REST](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#listsubscriptionsrequest) nor [RPC](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.ListSubscriptions) API provide a way to filter on the server side, so no there is no more efficient way to do this.

I imagine the gcloud code to do the filter is conceptually similar to what you wrote.